# Failed to execute Maven goal chekstyle/pmd : check

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, pmd, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I have the following configuration for fetching pmd and checkstyle rules [image]

And when I execute check goal I have this error for checkstyle:check - Failed during check style configuration : unable to parse configuration stream - Document root element "html", must match DOCTYPE root "null"

And for pmd:check - Could not read the ruleset... The reference to entity "RelayState" must end with the ';' delimiter

Seems to be, that problem is not with rule files, as soon as they worked fine a few days ago, and there weren't any changes in them.
Would be very grateful for any ideas!

Comment: Verify, what you get back when you visit "https://git.forge.lmig.com/projects/SF1/repos/swa-code-quality-rules-/raw/swa/pmd/pmd.xml" - this seems to be an internal server not available on the internet.

Does it return the file or does it return an html error page (e.g. 404 Not Found)?

Comment: @adangel it is located in internal servers it is not available in the internet.And yes, when i go by the link, it returns file

Comment: Can you give us the first few lines of your pmd.xml?